# Is there a way to search Trello for cards that have a label?

Tags: trello, search

I tried `Has:label` but without luck.

We use labels to assign the urgency/progress on a card (*Current*, *Urgent*, *Finished-Awaiting Review*, *Finished-Approved*).

When someone on our team starts working on a card, they assign it a priority (Current, Urgent, etc.). That way they can immediately see what's *currently* on their plate.

But I need a way to search for `Has:Label`.

The new search released today is click (`has:Sticker` etc.) but doesn't have `Has:label`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to search for cards that have any label; you can search for cards with a particular label with `label:red` or `label:urgent`, but not for the presence or absence of any label at all. We'll consider adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You may get closer to what you want by using the filter by labels feature of individual boards rather than by searching.

With the board selected and open:

Show Sidebar | Menu |  Filter Cards

Click to check each color label you wish to show.

If you select all labels, then all cards with any label will be shown on the board.

Cards without labels will not be shown in this case.

Comment: thanks, but my goal here is to see *all* of my Cards that have a label. (We use the Labels for the status. No label=It's not a current task. Solution is to use Green for "current" and other labels for urgency/status.

Comment: To be clear:  You mean all cards across all boards since this method will show All cards within the specific, selected board.